# How to disable search in site using sharepoint client object model

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, sharepoint-search

I need to disable search in site level using client Object Model. and search textbox in the top navigation.

Need help on this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

1.To exclude a SharePoint Online site collection from the search results, use this PowerShell script:

```
enter code here
#Load SharePoint Online Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server 
Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server 
Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://XXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXXX"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred= Get-Credential

Try {   
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
    $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username,$Cred.Password)
  
#Get the Web
$Web = $Ctx.Web
$Ctx.Load($Web)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

If($Web.NoCrawl)
{
    Write-host -f Yellow "Site is Already excluded from Search Index!"
}
Else
{
    #Exclude Site from Search
    $Web.NoCrawl = $True
    $Web.Update()
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-host -f Green "Site is Excluded from Search Index Successfully!"
}
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

2.Search box in SharePoint Online top navigation suite bar can be hidden with this PowerShell script:

```
$SiteURL = "https://XXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXXX"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential

Try {
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.UserName,$Cred.Password)

    #Get Web object
    $Web = $Ctx.Web
    $Ctx.Load($Web)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #Disable search in navigation bar
    $Web.SearchBoxInNavBar = 3
    $web.Update()
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: Thank you Allen. I need to implement this code in Client Object model. Can you please guide me on this